# Salesforce is showing invalid scope while running source push command

Tags: salesforce

I have implemented Territory, Now while pushing My Territeries's Opportuinity listing metadata to scratch org getting below error

`Invalid scope:MyTerritory`

Note: This is the out of box functionality, provided my sales force

Comment: Is territory management activated and configured in the scratch org?

Comment: yes, territory management is activated